# Print a new line in JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

How can I add a new line in my JSTL. I tried using `<br/>`,its not working for me. I have added JSTL tag in my JSP page.

```
<fieldset>
      <legend>Performance Testing:</legend>
        <c:forEach items="${histogram}" var="entry">
          Key = ${entry.key}, Value = ${entry.value}<br/>
         </c:forEach>

</fieldset>
```

Currently it is getting printed like this

```
Key = 83, Value = 1 Key = 37, Value = 25
```

I need something like this-

```
Key = 83, Value = 1
Key = 37, Value = 25
```

**Updated:-**

I tried debugging using Firebug and I found out this source code got generated-

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Performance Testing:</legend>
Key = 38, Value = 2
<br>
Key = 39, Value = 3
<br>
Key = 40, Value = 1
<br>
Key = 88, Value = 1
<br>
Key = 41, Value = 1
<br>
Key = 42, Value = 2
<br>
</fieldset>
```

And this also has line break, But still it get shows in a single line like in the below screenshot- Not how I wanted line by line as I mentioned above.

[image]

CSS that I have currently-

```
fieldset {
    margin: 0 0 22px 0;
    border: 1px solid #095D92;
    padding: 12px 17px;
    background-color: #DFF3FF;
}

legend {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    background-color: #095D92;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

Comment: Does the <br/> show up in the output when you view source in the browser?

Comment: The code looks legit. You're apparently not running the code you think you're running. Clean, rebuild, redeploy, restart.

Comment: @BalusC. Updated the question with more details.

Comment: @EJP Yes it get showed up.. See my updated question.

Comment: CSS issue perhaps? Could you have a rogue `display: inline` hanging around?

Comment: @TomG, Updated the question with CSS as always. Where do you want me to put that display:inline? in the fieldset css right?

Comment: Got that working. It was css issue. Figured that out. Thanks Guys.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way that cannot work unless the change never got deployed! Try clearing the server cache. If using tomcat, clear the tmp and work directories.

If the JSP is being included in another JSP, try touching both the JSPs and then have a look.

Also, I am not sure if HTML allows you to have line breaks within `<fieldset/>` tag. I maybe completely wrong on this one, but just to be sure put this piece of code in a regular `<div/>` tag and try.

Comment: Nope.. Doesn't work.. Tried that. I am working with Spring MVC, its a maven project. I did clean install also, still same problem.

Comment: Is any other change being propagated? Forget the `<br/>`, does it show up on the page if you added a line of text, for example?

Comment: I went and looked at the spec: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/forms.html#the-fieldset-element

Fieldset contains **flow** content, which apparently does not include `<br>` elements.

Comment: @TomG That's exactly what I was suspecting but the OP claimed he had tried it earlier. Anyways glad it is sorted :)